# Syncing Large, Rarely Changing Files

Tags: linux, rsync, file-transfer

I have a home server containing a fair amount of (legally-obtained) media files. When additions are made to this set when I am away, I would like to be able to sync these files to the remote copy on my laptop.

I know the general solution to this would be `rsync`, but it is too slow. I understand that it checks each file on the source and destination to look for changes, and this enumeration takes a large amount of time before any transfers begin.

Usually, only one or two files have been added and none of the existing ones have been changed. Is there a utility that can be run on-demand (not a constantly-running service like Syncthing or BitTorrent Sync) that is capable of avoiding the enumeration or keeping the list of files at each location cached?

(In an ideal world, there would also be a way to not re-sync files that had been deleted on the receiving end without also deleting them from the sending server.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the rsync man page, this might help. But probably not.

```
--size-only             skip files that match in size
```

Also in the man page, it is described how rsync decides if a file needs to be synchronized. It does not use checksums by default.

```
-c, --checksum
          This changes the way rsync checks if the files have been changed and are in need of a transfer.  Without this option, rsync uses a "quick check" that  (by  default)  checks  if  each
          file’s size and time of last modification match between the sender and receiver.  This option changes this to compare a 128-bit checksum for each file that has a matching size.  Gen‐
          erating the checksums means that both sides will expend a lot of disk I/O reading all the data in the files in the transfer (and this is prior to any reading that  will  be  done  to
          transfer changed files), so this can slow things down significantly.
```

It sounds like rsync uses checksums to verify the data once transferred, and this behaviour cannot be disabled. However, this person has a work around.

https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2007-June/017853.html

Though, I've never found rsync slow. Is it possible something else is going on? Are you doing this on some really old CPU?

There are other file file synchronization tools. How about Unison? I've never tried it.

How about writing your own script to do it? You could mount via NFS or SMB or use FTP, etc... and sync the data using your own simple code.

Comment: The source computer is running Ubuntu 14.04 on an AMD A4-5300 and the destination is a 2012 Macbook Pro: nothing ridiculously fast but not terrible either. The major bottleneck is probably the upload speed of the source network, but I would think that this wouldn't hurt the file enumeration too badly...in any case, I will try those options and perhaps letting `rsync` run overnight to match up timestamps that may be off from my manual `scp`-ing over the last few weeks and see if the next run is improved.

Comment: It this a massive list of files and/or deep directory structure by any chance? I've seen this make rsync slow to start (on an older computer).

Comment: Everything works now that I let it run once through and update timestamps--my original copy did not preserve those and caused `rsync` much unhappiness. The `--modify-window` and `--size-only` options sped this process along.

Answer (score 0):

The reason rsync takes a long time is because it needs to read all the data at both ends in order to create comparison maps. Once the filesystem's are in sync as of a particular timestamp you only need to rsync the files which have changed since that timestamp (touch a file on completion of rsync then use find....-newer...). Alternatively use AFS.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` check timestamps and size before checking data.  This is relatively fast, but there is a delay before transfers begin.  This is normally quite fast.  However, the Windows FAT file system has a timestamp resolution of 2 seconds.  This can cause timestamp checks to fail when compared to a system with a resolution of 1 second.  Adding `--modify-window=1` allows timestamps to differ by one second and resolve the problem.

It may help to use `--whole-file` for media files as there is likely no reason to move file deltas.  However, if you updated ID3 tags, deltas may be faster.

A solution like `unison` which is rsync based, may work well if you make changes on both the file server and laptop.

Comment: Oh! Although I am using Ubuntu and OS X in this case, I did realize that the destination device is ExFAT formatted, which also has a 2-second timestamp interval. I will try the `--modify-window` option as well.